SVG viewbox, Safari is positioning (relative / absolute) based on viewbox, so it's fixed to that size regardless on the screensize change


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?AdobeSVGViewer save="snapshot"?>
   


<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     viewBox="-20 -20 800 1440"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet"
     width="100%" height="100%"
     id="piramida">


     
     
     <defs>
     <style>


#piramida {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
 to {
    opacity: 1;
 }
}
 text {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    fill: #595959;
}


.st0 {
    fill: #ffffff;
}
.st1 {
    fill: #595959333;
}

#aniplay,
#anistop {
    cursor: pointer;
}


  #aniplay path, #anistop path {
            fill: #007FAD; 
        }

  #aniplay:hover path, #anistop:hover path {
            fill: #033446; 
        }


[id^="f"],[id^="m"], [id^="rib"]{
    cursor: pointer;
}



#xtext1, #xtext2 {

 font-weight:bold;
}

tspan {
    font-size:16px;
}

#title {
    font-size:18px;
}

#title-info {
    font-size:18px;
}

#logo-surs {
    transform: scale(0.5) translate(5%, 177%);
}

#ribbon-nudge {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#ribbon-nudge:hover {
    fill: #555555; 
}

::selection {
    background-color: #007fad; 
    fill: white; /* White text */
}


::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #007fad;
    fill: white;
}



  #selectAllButton {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: #007FAD;
    border: 1px solid #007FAD;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 340px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #selectAllButton:hover {
    background-color: #013D54; 
    border: 2px solid #013D54;
    color: #fff;
  }
/* The slider itself */
.fancy-slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.fancy-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background:#013D54; /* Lighter or different color on hover */
}

/* The slider handle (thumb) - for Webkit browsers */
.fancy-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #007FAD;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -7.5px;
}

/* The slider handle (thumb) - for Firefox */
.fancy-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #007FAD;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* The track of the slider (specific to WebKit browsers) */
.fancy-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: #C6C6C6;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.fancy-slider::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: #C6C6C6;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Optional: Style for the focus outline */
.fancy-slider:focus {
    
}


#decrement {
    margin-right:10px;
     margin-top:-1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#increment {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:-1px;
     font-weight:bold;
     border-radius: 50px;
}

  #aniplay:hover path, #anistop:hover path {
            fill: #033446; 
        }


.slider-button {
    background-color: #007FAD;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}

.slider-button:hover{
    background:#013D54;
}


.sliders_control input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background: #013D54; /* Color change on hover */
}

.sliders_control input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
    background: #013D54;
}

.sliders_control input[type='range']::-ms-thumb:hover {
    background: #013D54;
}


.vertical-slider-container {
   position: relative;
 
}

.vertical-slider-container .range_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 35% auto;
}

.sliders_control {
     position: absolute;
    width: 530px;
    top: 50%; /* Adjusted for better centering */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    will-change:transform;
}

.vertical-slider-container .form_control {
  margin-top:20px;
}

.vertical-slider-container input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {

   -webkit-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px;
    background: #007FAD;
     pointer-events: all;
    cursor: pointer; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 0px; 
}




.vertical-slider-container input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
 
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px; 
    background: #007FAD; 
     pointer-events: all;
    cursor: pointer; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
}



#fromSlider {
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.vertical-slider-container input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 85%;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ddd;

    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.vertical-slider-container #fromSlider,
.vertical-slider-container #toSlider {
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.vertical-slider-container #fromSlider {
    top: 27px;
    background: transparent;
}

.vertical-slider-container #toSlider {
    top: 15px;

}

.vertical-slider-container input[type="range"] {
 width: 100%; 
    height: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.vertical-slider-container input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb,
.vertical-slider-container input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb,
.vertical-slider-container input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
}






.not-safari {
  min-width: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

.not-safari select {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  padding: 0.675em 6em 0.675em 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #caced1;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #595959;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight:bold!important;
}

.not-safari::before,
.not-safari::after {
  --size: 0.3rem;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:5.5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.not-safari::before {
  border-left: var(--size) solid transparent;
  border-right: var(--size) solid transparent;
  border-bottom: var(--size) solid black;
  top: 40%;
}

.not-safari::after {
  border-left: var(--size) solid transparent;
  border-right: var(--size) solid transparent;
  border-top: var(--size) solid black;
  top: 55%;
}


    </style>



<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="pyracode.js"></script>


    </defs>
<defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> <!-- Adjusted for a slightly softer shadow -->
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" result="offsetblur"/> <!-- No horizontal offset, small vertical offset -->
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.25"/> <!-- Increased opacity for a darker shadow -->
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode/> <!-- Shadow layer -->
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> <!-- Original graphic -->
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
</defs>

    <rect x="0" y="300" width="760" height="1000" rx="15" fill="#fff" filter="url(#shadow)"/>






<g font-family="arial" >

<!-- <text x="50" y="1000" font-size="18px" fill="#595959" font-weight="bold">Prikaži spremembe v času</text> -->
<!--<rect x="725" y="635" height="20" width="55" fill="white"/> -->
<!-- <text id="status" x="730" y="200" font-size="18px">Izbrano leto:</text> -->
<!-- <rect x="790" y="635" height="20" width="100" fill="white"/> -->


<g onclick="AniStop()" id="anistop" display="none">
<title>Ustavi animacijo</title>
<rect x="80" y="120.5" height="25" width="25" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1px" stroke="none
" rx="5" ry="5"/>
<rect x="80" y="1020" class="st0" width="18.7" height="17.3"/>
   <rect x="80" y="1020" width="25" height="25" stroke-width="1px" stroke="none" fill="transparent" rx="5" ry="5"/>
<path d="M24 4C12.95 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.95 20 20 20 20-8.95 20-20S35.05 4 24 4zm-2 28h-4V16h4v16zm8 0h-4V16h4v16z" fill="#969696" transform="scale(0.7)  translate(110, 1448) "/>

</g>
</g>
<!--DATA PANEL GROUP-->
<!--
<g id="datapanel" font-family="arial, sans-serif" font-size="18px" display="none">
    <rect x="725" y="410" width="300" height="200" fill="white"/>
    <line x1="730" x2="980" y1="438" y2="438" stroke-width="1" stroke="#999999"/>
    <line x1="730" x2="980" y1="495" y2="495" stroke-width="1" stroke="#999999"/>
    <line x1="730" x2="980" y1="552" y2="552" stroke-width="1" stroke="#999999"/>
    
    <text>-->
<g id="datapanel" font-family="arial, sans-serif" font-size="18px" display="none">


    <!-- Draw the background rectangle with more padding and less intense shadow -->
    <rect x="355" y="20" width="405" height="250" rx="15" fill="#fff" filter="url(#shadow)"/>

    <!-- Your existing text content, with no changes needed -->
    <text>
  <tspan x="375" y="50" font-size="18px" id="title-info" font-weight="bold" fill="#595959">Informacije o prebivalcih:</tspan>

<tspan x="375" y="90">Starost:</tspan>
<tspan id="text1" dx="5" font-weight="bold"> </tspan>

<tspan x="375" y="115">Rojeni:</tspan>
<tspan id="text2" dx="5" font-weight="bold"> </tspan>

<tspan x="375" y="157">Število:</tspan>
<tspan id="text3" dx="5" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end"> </tspan>

<tspan x="375" y="182">Delež:</tspan>
<tspan id="text0" dx="5" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end"> </tspan>

<tspan x="375" y="224">Moški:</tspan>
<tspan id="text4" dx="5" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end"> </tspan>
<tspan id="text6" dx="5" font-weight="bold"> </tspan>

<tspan x="375" y="251">Ženske:</tspan>
<tspan id="text5" dx="5" font-weight="bold" font-size="18" text-anchor="end"> </tspan>
<tspan id="text7" dx="5" font-weight="bold">  </tspan>



    </text>
</g>


 

 <!-- Define filter for shadow -->

    <!-- Draw the background rectangle with shadow -->
    <rect x="0" y="20" width="320" height="250" rx="15" fill="#fff" filter="url(#shadow)"/>

    <!-- Your existing content -->
    <text> 
        <tspan id="title" x="20" y="50"  font-weight="bold" >Izberi regijo:</tspan>
    </text>
    
    <foreignObject x="20" y="80" width="300" height="100">
        <div class="custom-select" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <select style="font-size:16px;font-weight:normal">
            </select>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>



<text id="yrbeg" x="135" y="1000" text-anchor="middle"> </text>
<text id="yrend" x="635" y="1000" text-anchor="middle"> </text>

<text id="yeartext" x="310" y="1000" font-size="16px"  font-weight="bold"> </text>

  <foreignObject x="120" y="1010" width="530" height="40">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="slider-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
      <button type="button" title="Premakni za leto nazaj" aria-label="Premakni za leto nazaj" onclick="RibbonNudge(-1)" id="decrement" class="slider-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="#ffffff" d="M432 256c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32L48 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l352 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32z"/></svg></button>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="999" value="999" step="1" class="fancy-slider" id="myRange" ></input>
   
    <button type="button" title= "Premakni za leto naprej" aria-label="Premakni za leto naprej" onclick="RibbonNudge(+1)" id="increment" class="slider-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="#ffffff" d="M256 80c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32V224H48c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32H192V432c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32V288H400c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H256V80z"/></svg></button>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>


<text  id="age0" x="135" y="1095" text-anchor="middle">0 let</text>
 <text id="age99" x="635" y="1095" text-anchor="middle">99 let</text>

<text id="statustext"  x="270" y="1095" font-size="16" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-weight="bold" >Izberi starost ali starostni rang</text>
  <text id="hinttext"  x="270" y="1060" font-size="16" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" fill="#595959"> </text>
  <foreignObject xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="70" y="1100" width="624" height="40">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="slider-container" style="width: 100%; height: 20%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <div class="vertical-slider-container">
<div class="range_container"> 
    <div class="sliders_control">
        <input id="fromSlider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="999"/>
        <input id="toSlider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="999"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form_control">
        <div class="form_control_container">
            <div class="form_control_container__time">Min</div>
            <input class="form_control_container__time__input" type="number" id="fromInput" value="0" min="0" max="999"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form_control_container">
            <div class="form_control_container__time">Max</div>
            <input class="form_control_container__time__input" type="number" id="toInput" value="0" min="0" max="999"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</foreignObject>



</svg>



I have an interactive SVG file with some foreign objects. The issue is that as soon as the element has position:relative/absolute at any point (parent, children), it's fixed to the viewbox width and height (stays in the same place, disappearing eventually), while everything else manages to resize with the SVG.
(I'm shortening the file)
some CSS:
 svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

  .vertical-slider-container {
       position: relative;
       z-index:200;
        will-change:transform; //need this because it will not draw the slider correctly, if i'd add the transform:translateZ(0), it would act the same as having a "position".
    }

.vertical-slider-container #fromSlider,
.vertical-slider-container #toSlider {
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative; //need it to you two sliders together.
}

.vertical-slider-container .range_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

the SVG:
    <svg version="1.1"
         baseProfile="full"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         viewBox="-20 -20 800 1440"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
         width="800" height="1400"
         id="svg-item">



      <foreignObject xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="70" y="1100" width="624" height="40">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="slider-container" style="width: 100%; height: 20%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
        <div class="vertical-slider-container">
    <div class="range_container"> 
        <div class="sliders_control">
            <input id="fromSlider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="999"/>
            <input id="toSlider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="999"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form_control">
            <div class="form_control_container">
                <div class="form_control_container__time">Min</div>
                <input class="form_control_container__time__input" type="number" id="fromInput" value="0" min="0" max="999"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form_control_container">
                <div class="form_control_container__time">Max</div>
                <input class="form_control_container__time__input" type="number" id="toInput" value="0" min="0" max="999"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>


Can you write you code in StackOverflow Snippet syntax With the [<>] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Ok, I've pasted it in, but it seems the bug is not reproducible within SO. Other than the width of the element resizing when changing the width. In the actual file, the element stays fixed in place.
